# 'Undefined' value when using EntityRecognizer.resolveTime

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using the LuisRecognizer.recognize() method to find datetimeV2 entities in a waterfall dialog in my bot, and EntityRecognizer.resolveTime() to resolve the answer as follows:

```
builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(results.response, process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL, function (err, intents, entities) {
        console.log(entities);
        if (entities) {
               var entity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.date');
               var resolvedTime = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime(entities);
               console.log(entity);
               console.log(resolvedTime);
        }
    });
```

When I test it, the `console.log(entity)` prints the following json:

```
{ entity: 'mañana',
    type: 'builtin.datetimeV2.date',
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 5,
    resolution: { values: [Object] } }
```

But the second console.log(resolvedTime) prints `undefined` value.
I also tried `builder.EntityRecognizer.parseTime(entities);` with same results.

I am able to extract the date from the resolution field in the response, but that solution is not practical with more complex utterances (like range dates).

Comment: Your code snippet works well on my side, what do you mean `because I've used the builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity('') before and it works properly` exactly?

Comment: I mean that I used `builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.datetime')` before in the code, with the LuisRecognizer and the dialogs without problems. I am having these issues when calling LUIS manually with LuisRecognizer.recognize().

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT you were right, the code snippet worked well, I was having an issue concatenating an string with the response in my code. I updated my question to reflect the real problem now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the source code of [resolveTime function](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/7b70cfdd2c05c4af9986f3d7acf9c571af1b8298/Node/core/lib/dialogs/EntityRecognizer.js#L31), we can find this function do not convert the `datetimeV2` data type. So you got `undefined`.

However, you still can leverage `entity.resolution` to get the date for `datetimeV2`.

- For `builtin.datetimeV2.date` date type:

  ```
  var date = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.date');
  console.log(date.resolution.values[0].value);
  ```
- For `builtin.datetimeV2.daterange`:

  ```
  var daterange = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.daterange');
  console.log(daterange.resolution.values[0]);
  ```

  Whose object should be like:

  ```
  {end:"2018-01-10"
  start:"2018-01-09"
  timex:"(2018-01-09,2018-01-10,P1D)"
  type:"daterange"}
  ```

Comment: That info is very helpful. I think that the EntityRecognizer documentation should reflect this since datetimeV2 is now the predefined entity type. Hope they include a resolution in future releases, it's very complicated to handle certain utterances, specially when LUIS identifies more than one entity and presents multiple resolutions. Thank you @GaryLiu-MSFT